# Extract audio-less video from .mp4 file using Gstreamer

Tags: video, streaming, gstreamer

I am working on video streaming between a server and client, here server will send audio-less video (i.e only video from .mp4 file), and client will receive only video and play in the sink element. Shared below the used pipeline and obtained logs when server and client are run in two individual TI DM8148 boards.

Server pipeline:

```
gst-launch-0.10 -v filesrc location=/home/sample1/Holy.mp4 ! qtdemux name=demux ! multiqueue ! h264parse ! mpegtsmux name=mux ! udpsink host=192.168.10.11  port=5551 dec.
```

Server logs:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ....
Pipeline is PREROLLING ....
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0.GstPad:sink0: caps = video/x-h264, level=(string)3.1, profile=(string)high, codec_data=(buffer)0164001fffe1001a6764001fac248805005bb011000003000100000300328f1832a001000568ee32
c8b0, width=(int)1280, height=(int)720, framerate=(fraction)25/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1
    /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0.GstPad:src0: caps = video/x-h264, level=(string)3.1, profile=(string)high, codec_data=(buffer)0164001fffe1001a6764001fac248805005bb011000003000100000300328f1832a001000568ee32c
8b0, width=(int)1280, height=(int)720, framerate=(fraction)25/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1
    /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstH264Parse:h264parse0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, level=(string)3.1, profile=(string)high, codec_data=(buffer)0164001fffe1001a6764001fac248805005bb011000003000100000300328f1832a001000568ee32c8b
0, width=(int)1280, height=(int)720, framerate=(fraction)25/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1
    /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstH264Parse:h264parse0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-h264, level=(string)3.1, profile=(string)high, width=(int)1280, height=(int)720, framerate=(fraction)25/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au
    /GstPipeline:pipeline0/MpegTsMux:mux.GstPad:sink_64: caps = video/x-h264, level=(string)3.1, profile=(string)high, width=(int)1280, height=(int)720, framerate=(fraction)25/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au
    /GstPipeline:pipeline0/MpegTsMux:mux.GstPad:src: caps = video/mpegts, systemstream=(boolean)true, packetsize=(int)188, streamheader=(buffer)< 47400030a600ffffffffffffffffffffffffff0000b00d0001c100000001e020a2c32941,474020308b00ffffffffffffffffffffffffff0002b0280001c10000e040f00c050448444d5688040ffffcfc1be040f00a050848444d56ff1b443ffba2e249 >
    /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSink:udpsink0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/mpegts, systemstream=(boolean)true, packetsize=(int)188, streamheader=(buffer)< 47400030a600fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff0000b00d0001c100000001e020a2c32941, 474020308b00fff
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff0002b0280001c10000e040f00c050448444d5688040ffffcfc1be040f00a050848444d56ff1b443ff
ba2e249 >
    Caught interrupt -- handling interrupt.
    Interrupt: Stopping pipeline ...
    Execution ended after 29454849250 ns.
    Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
    Setting pipeline to READY ...
```

Client Pipeline:

```
gst-launch-0.10 -v udpsrc port=5551 ! mpegtsdemux name=demux ! multiqueue ! h264parse ! ffdec_h264 ! v4l2sink demux.
```

Client logs:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ....

** (gst-launch-0.10:1724): CRITICAL **: gst_v4l2sink_sync_rotation: assertion `v4l2_ioctl (fd, VIDIOC_S_CTRL, &c
ontrol) >= 0' failed

** (gst-launch-0.10:1724): CRITICAL **: gst_v4l2sink_sync_rotation: assertion `v4l2_ioctl (fd, VIDIOC_S_CTRL, &c
ontrol) >= 0' failed

** (gst-launch-0.10:1724): CRITICAL **: gst_v4l2sink_sync_flip: assertion `v4l2_ioctl (fd, VIDIOC_S_CTRL, &contr
ol) >= 0' failed
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL .....
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ....
New clock: MpegTSClock
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstMpegTSDemux:demux: pat-info = ((GValueArray*) 0x19f740)
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstMpegTSDemux:demux: pmt-info = ((MpegTsPmtInfo*) 0x10bc60)
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0.GstPad:sink0: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-s
tream, alignment=(string)nal
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0.GstPad:src0: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-st
ream, alignment=(string)nal
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstH264Parse:h264parse0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stre
am, alignment=(string)nal
```

Two TI boards connected back to back, one as sender and other as receiver. First run server and then run client pipeline.

observation: Server sends data and client too receives it, as led's on both boards blink. But no video played on client side.

question 1. how can I confirm it is only required video packets are sent?

Can anyone help me to correct the pipeline to send only video from .mp4 and receive only video.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi all , can anybody provide solution on the above problem. I am still facing this issue.